# Netbeans 8.0.2 CPU Usage

Tags: cpu-usage, netbeans-8

I recently got a new laptop. It has a Core i7 8th gen processor, so plenty of power. However, the fan runs constantly whenever I start NetBeans. I searched for solutions and found that it seems to have something to do with the task scans in the background. One user suggested pressing CTRL + 6, then CTRL + W to shut down the task scanning. This actually works and brings the CPU back down to 0 when NetBeans is idle. However, I have to do it every 15 minutes to keep my super loud fan at bay. Any ideas on how to disable task scanning more permanently than CTRL + 6, then CTRL + w?

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you might try to quieten your fan:

- With respect to completely stopping Task Scanning, there is no functionality built into NetBeans 8.x to do that, but there is a plugin available named [MasterFileSystemSuspend](http://wiki.netbeans.org/MasterFileSystemSuspend). Use **Tools > Plugins > Settings** tab **> Add**, then **Tools > Plugins > Downloaded** tab **> Add Plugins...** to add the plugin.

Once the plugin is installed, a button with the tooltip **Pause I/O Checks** is added to the toolbar:

[image: MasterFileSystemSuspend82]

Clicking the button will suspend/resume scanning. That functionality is already built in to [the nightly builds of NetBeans 8.2](http://bits.netbeans.org/download/trunk/nightly/latest/) and also [Apache NetBeans 9.0 RC.1](http://netbeans.apache.org/download/index.html). To display the button ensure that **View > Toolbars > Performance** is checked:

[image: MasterFileSystemSuspend90]

- Apart from Task Scanning there is another form of scanning which is performed whenever focus is returned to NetBeans from other applications:

**Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files** tab **> Enable auto-scanning of sources**

[image: nbAutoScanning]

If you never change NetBeans project files outside of NetBeans you can safely uncheck this setting. This is its help information:

> When selected, the IDE will scan the source code of projects to detect
>   any files that were modified externally. Scanning is triggered when
>   the focus is returned to the IDE, for example when the user returns to
>   the IDE from another application.
>
> If your sources are only modified from within the IDE, you can
>   probably disable auto-scanning with little risk of encountering
>   problems. Disabling auto-scanning may improve  IDE performance if you
>   are working on large projects.
>
> Auto-scanning is enabled by default.

- Also review this [NetBeans FAQ providing hints on improving performance](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqScanningAndIndexingPerformanceHints) with respect to indexing and scanning.
- Finally, apart from suppressing scanning, another simple change to reduce I/O and improve performance is to close projects that you aren't actively working on. There is an overhead associated with each open project, so it is pointless to have unused projects open.